# PHP-Files received in $_REQUEST

Tags: php, file, request

Regarding my question here : [PHP uses GET method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580411/php-uses-get-method)

I have PHP 5.3.27 on the server that I use and I always get the files I upload in $_REQUEST, while $_FILES array is always empty ...Why?
I am using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on my form.

**EDIT:**

Here is my form :

```
<form action="addScript.php" methot="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <tr>
                <td>Produt name : </td><td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Product description : </td><td><textarea rows="5" cols="40" name="description" id="description"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Price (USD $) : </td><td><input type="text" name="price" id="price" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Profile Picture : </td><td><input type="file" name="profilepic" id="profilepic" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td>Other pictures : </td><td>
                <div id="pictures" style="border:1px solid black;"><table>
                <tr><td>1</td><td><input type="file" id="pic1" name="pic1" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>2</td><td><input type="file" id="pic2" name="pic2" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>3</td><td><input type="file" id="pic3" name="pic3" /></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Add" /></td>
    </form>
```

Comment: please post the html form

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)

Comment: @Volkan Ulukut : The form is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580411/php-uses-get-method

Comment: @stckrboy : It is not a duplicate because I don't want to know what enctype="multipart/form-data" is. I want to know why I don't receive my files in the $_FILES variable but in $_REQUEST.

Comment: Aha, my apologies. I read your sentence and somehow missed the ? after your 'Why'. Long day is long

Answer (score 0):

You get the following information for each file:

```
$_FILES['field_name']['name']
$_FILES['field_name']['size']
$_FILES['field_name']['type']
$_FILES['field_name']['tmp_name']
```

Comment: I can't because  var_dump($_FILES) return an empty array.

Comment: ok. could you please include the code of HTML form, in your question.

Comment: Check your php.ini file and verify the file_uploads directive is set On.

Comment: I finally managed to solve the problem. I somehow forgot to close the body tag X_x...Thank you for your time :)

Comment: I forgot to close the body tag in the page with the form.